# How to vertically align text of different sizes with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Alright, so I've gone through and have tried several different solutions but I haven't found one that works the way I want it to so hence me reaching out for help.

Here is an example of my current code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <h3>
      Operating Systems:
    </h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <ul>
      <li>Windows</li>
      <li>Linux</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me the following:[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeKic.png)

By adding the following style to the columns:

```
<style>
.col-height {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  height: 100%;
</style>
```

I get it to display what I want when it is expanded with the text from each column aligned along the top.

The issue with this is that when resized to a small size it displays it like it is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yG8IE.png) where as I want it to display as the hardware section does.

So here is my question: Is there a way with bootstrap to get it to display how I want it in both cases or do I have to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media query to only apply the centering styles on larger widths. The margin of the h3 is effecting the vertical alignment so you may want to adjust that. Also IMO, flexbox is a better alignment method...

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .flex {
        display:flex;
        align-items:center;
    }
    h3 {
        margin-top:5px;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/hR8GJDwdL1

Comment: Thank you very much, not quite what I needed but got me to what I needed. By putting the col-height code inside the media query as you described above, I was able to achieve the desired effect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing col-md-x to col-xs-x

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, that doesn't work though. In some cases it is making things worse.